# How to get utf8 rss feed?

Tags: haskell, utf-8, rss

I'm trying to use the package [RSS](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/feed) with UTF8 string with no avail. (i don't want to use HXT which works, i just want to understand where i'm wrong)

In ghci when i put "test" i just get garbage with character such as "é".

If i get the string from reading a file with `UTF8.readFile` and send it to `parseFromString` it works, but when i download and use `getRespBody` it doesn't.

Here is my sample code :

```hs
import Network.HTTP                   (simpleHTTP,  getRequest, getResponseBody)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Text.Feed.Import (parseFeedString)
import Text.RSS.Syntax 
import Text.Feed.Types (Feed(..))
import Prelude hiding (putStrLn)
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (putStrLn)
import Data.ByteString.UTF8 (fromString)

siteUrl  =  "http://radiofrance-podcast.net/podcast09/rss_11549.xml"

type Links = [(String,String,String)]


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--   Main function 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

test = getLinks siteUrl >>= mapM_ (putStrLn.fromString) 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--     Retrieve titles
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

getLinks:: String -> IO [String]
getLinks url = simpleHTTP (getRequest url) >>= getResponseBody >>= parseDoc 


parseDoc d = do
 let RSSFeed rss = (fromJust . parseFeedString ) d 
    items = rssItems.rssChannel $ rss
    titles = map (fromJust.rssItemTitle)    items
 return $  titles
```

---

**Update**: 
thanks to Roman's answer, i have modified my code. Here are the modification for anyone who may be interested.

```
import Codec.Binary.UTF8.String       (decodeString)  -- <-- added

getLinks:: String -> IO [String]
getLinks url = simpleHTTP (getRequest url) >>= getResponseBody >>= parseDoc.decodeString -- <-- modified
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `simpleHTTP` may return `String`-based responses is a bit confusing. In reality they are not Unicode strings, but byte strings that contain the HTTP response as is. No automatic decoding is done.

So, you need to decode the http response before passing it to feed parsing functions (e.g. using the `encoding` or `utf8-string` package).

You probably want to extract the source encoding information from the `Content-Type` http header or from the RSS document itself.

Comment: Thank you, i re-read the utf8-string package and the function `decode`made the trick. i will update the code to share the solution.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, but I used `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8.unpack` to get the String. It doesn't work, either. It has costed me some hours to find the cause and finally this hint. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! And you are right, `bytestring` should be preferred to `utf8-string` or `encoding` in 2018. On the other hand, in 2018 there's hardly a reason to use the `HTTP` package in the first place. Use `http-conduit` instead which works with bytestrings out of the box.

Comment: Thank you again. I'll try to migrate to `http-conduit`.